# delete files that are not in git lfs in some certain folder

Tags: git

I am using git lfs large file system. Now, I have a folder:
FOLDER1/

containing thousands of folders, within which only 10 of them are on the git lfs server. now I want to clean everything other than the 10 folder to clean up space. what should I do? Thank you. I only want to do this for Folder1 and nothing else.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to delete all contents of a folder except for 10 files? Are these files currently within your repository, in LFS, or not at all?

Comment: they are all in the lfs repository. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to remove them moving forward, or remove them from history entirely?

Comment: I just want to remove them from the entire history, as if they never existed.

Comment: Ok. Have you looked into filter-branch? It's a heavy-handed and potentially dangerous command, but it can do what you're looking for. https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage/